# I lost all my stuff in Minecraft because of a disconnect

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I was playing on a realm in *Minecraft* on my Nintendo Switch. I was using my hotspot and then it disconnected from the internet and I got disconnected from the realm.

When I got back on, I spawned where I had previously set my spawn point. It took me 1 minute to get back to where I had supposedly “died” (or where I disconnected from) and nothing was there. I’m really frustrated because it’s hours of hard work gone.

Answer (score 0):

Your items likely despawned because of some of the following reasons:

- You died near spawn and spawn is always loaded, so the despawn timer is always running.
- Another player was near you but didn't pick your items up, so the despawn timer is still running.

You can either re-acquire the items or enable cheats due to Bedrock's tight stance on "playing legit".